# Laravel 4 wont autoload provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

So I have created a new provider and facade and added them to my app configuration. Problem Is that I get an error:

```
 Class 'Cergis\View\Helper\SentryViewProvider' not found
```

The class is using a PSR-0 naming scheme and I have verified that it's correct by adding

```
"psr-0": {
    "Cergis\\": [
        "vendor/cergis/logger/src/",
        "vendor/cergis/sentry-view/src/"
    ]
}
```

If I do this and run `composer dump-autoload` then it works without issue. But for some reason it's unable to do so without me manually telling it where to find the classes in the vendor folder. I have tried removing everything and starting fresh, running `composer dump-autoload` before adding it to app.providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` and check if `Cergis\View\Helper\SentryViewProvider` is there, if not then add these line at the start of the array:

```
'SentryViewProvider' => $baseDir . 'View\Helper\SentryViewProvider.php,'
```

Feel free to edit the value to match the path

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran `composer dump` since creating them?